# Fractional exponents - adding the exponent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this question for which I need to simplify the expression so that only positive exponents occur, and assuming the variables are positive:

$$x^{2/5} x^{1/4} x^{-1/2}$$

The answer is supposed to be $x^{3/20}$ I think, but I keep getting $1/x^{1/20}$

Can anyone please help me with how I can get to the answer? Much appreciated!!

Comment: Are you writing $2/5=0.2$?

Comment: I mistakenly changed the fraction 2/5 to 4/20 hence why i was always resulting in -1/20. Solved the issue - thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

$$\huge{x^{\frac{2}{5}}x^{\frac{1}{4}}x^{\frac{-1}{2}}=x^{\frac{2}{5}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}}=x^{\frac{8+5-10}{20}}=x^{\frac{3}{20}}}$$

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I made the silliest mistake by changing the 2/5 to 4/20. Thanks a million!

Comment: YOU'RE WELCOME!!!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Use $a^{m_1} \cdot a^{m_2} \cdot \ldots \cdot a^{m_n}=a^{m_1+m_2+...+m_n}$.